# Non-EU citizen studying in Italy wish to travel to Belgium and my resident permit is not ready

Tags: schengen

I am non-EU citizen and I arrived in Italy a month ago for my studies. I wish to travel to Belgium to visit my boyfriend over the Christmas holiday, yet my resident permit is still not out. Will I be able to travel with only my passport and visa without the authorities asking for my resident permit?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Schengen Visa, you are allowed to go to any Schengen area with only your visa and passport until it is valid.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Italian national visa **type C** or more likely **D** you can travel around Schengen area with no fear. Usually inside Schengen area passport is needed only to prove your identity.